# How to set a approval for build in yaml in Azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-server-2019

How to set a approval for build in yaml in Azure devops ?                                                                               I know its available for deployment process but I want to know the approval set up for build in yaml

Answer (score 0):

**You can set approvals for the resources used by the YAML pipeline.**

For example, you can set approval for agent that used by the YAML pipeline. So that every time the YAML pipeline needs to run, approvers need to click "Approve" to agree the pipeline to use agent. After approving, the pipeline will continue to run.

If you only needs to set approval for deployment part of yaml pipeline, you can set approval for environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can add approvals for your pipelines using .yaml files.

```
- deployment: Approval
displayName: 'Deployment Approval'
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest' # optional
environment: 'Production' # Replace with the name of your deployment environment (e.g., Production, Staging, etc.)
strategy:
  runOnce:
    deploy:
      steps:
      - script: echo "Waiting for approval from admin!"
```

the word "Approval" means, Your pipeline will ask for an approval before going to the mentioned environment.

- deployment -> Job type

Note: Take care of the yaml file alignment and double check the value of "**environment**" for correct behaviour